# Physics Riddle - Know Plant Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, earth, thought-experiment

I hope it's OK to ask here, because it's pretty much as basic as physics can get. So here it is:

I have a hot air balloon that can rise to any altitude I'd like, a precise watch, a sandbag, a weigh scale and a ruler. I can neglect the air friction in my calculation. Also, it's given that the things which impact the most on earth mass are iron and water.

I can use only these to evaluate the following:

- The earth radius
- Earth mass
- Gravitational Constant

I'd like a guidance on how to evaluate the first one.

Thanks

Comment: So what have you done to solve your homework?

Comment: Please show your working out and specifically where you are having difficulty.

Comment: @CuriousOne Well, nothing more than some thinking and doodling, which got me to nowhere. That is why I asked for a guidance. I don't want someone to solve my homework for me. Just a little help or how to approach it.

Comment: You didn't even show the doodling. Vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you don't appear to have is a direct means to measure your altitude. But you have enough tools to do the job.

First, weight your sandbag "on the ground". Let's say the weight is $W$. Now climb to a very high altitude (you said you could go to any altitude... go high). Find an altitude at which the weight of the sandbag is noticeably reduced, and note the new weight.

Now drop the sandbag, and time its fall back to earth.

Express the force of gravity as a function of height by doing a Taylor expansion of the force of gravity equation:

$$F = \frac{GMm}{r^2}\\
= \frac{GMm}{(R+h)^2}\\
=\frac{GMm}{R^2(1+h/R)^2}\\
=\frac{GMm}{R^2}(1-\frac{2h}{R})$$

Thus the ratio $\frac{h}{R}$ can be determined from the reduction in weight as you went high.

Converting the drop time to height requires you to use the same equation - there's a small correction compared to the assumption that the gravitational force is uniform.

Figure that bit out, and you end up with a set of equations from which you can solve for the radius of the earth.

Note that it is more important to get the weight change right than the exact height: the accuracy of $R$ is directly related to the accuracy with which you measure $h$ which is closely related to your accuracy in timing the fall (for which you were given a "precise watch"). The trickiest part of the measurement is determining that the weight has gone down by a noticeable amount - say the change is 1% (corresponding to a height of about 33 km, but then we were told this balloon could do anything), then you need to be able to measure weight to 1 part in $10^4$ (0.01%) in order to get 1% accuracy on the height. In contrast, the relationship between time and height is quadratic, so it's easier to be accurate (assuming you can see the moment the sandbag hits the ground from 33 km up...)

Comment: I would love you to show me how you measure the fall of a sandbag with a ruler to the precision needed... I don't think that's a good solution to the problem. If we assume that the ruler is of arbitrary length, it's much easier to measure the curvature of the planet directly. The product of $GM$, by the way, can not be separated with this approach, and he was asked to measure both independently.

Comment: @Yes. I don't think it is. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne - I use the "precise watch" not the ruler, to measure the height by timing the drop. And the question was just for guidance to the first part - I did not attempt to do anything about G and M, only to estimate R. No limits were given on the precision that could be achieved with either the watch or the scale - and yes, I am assuming that the ruler is not long enough to measure the height of the balloon when it's high enough that the scales register a difference.

Comment: @Floris: I don't think the idea is to use the ruler to measure the precise altitude of the ballon. If it is, the question was asked by an atrociously poor teacher. On the other hand, that's not an easily rejected hypothesis. :-)